# PHP: strpos() fails to find '“'

Tags: php, string

I looked at the other question, but the answer is not true for me.

$text:

```
(string:104) “The diamond cannot be polished without friction, nor the man perfected without trials.” Chinese Proverb
```

Yet...

```
strpos($text, '“')
```

=== false, upon inspection.

Same with:

```
strpos($text, "“")
strpos($text, "\“")
strpos($text, '\“')
```

Ideas?

EDIT: it is a $_POST variable grabbed from a textarea, if that makes a difference. The value is precisely

```
“The diamond cannot be polished without friction, nor the man perfected without trials.” Chinese Proverb
```

Comment: I don't know how you test it. But, my test got the result. Try to add more character in front of your `$text` and do `strpos($text, '“')` again. It should produce non `'0'` value.

Comment: The string contains 104 *characters*. If those are UTF-8 encoded smart quotes, that should be 108 *bytes*, yet `var_dump` (I assume?) prints 104 bytes. So it's either an encoding mismatch or these are not the quotes you are looking for.

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/cmxok

Comment: i get 0 for strpos('“The diamond cannot be polished without friction, nor the man perfected without trials.” Chinese Proverb', '“') too. it's got something to do with being a variable from $_POST perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the quote character `“` found in the text is a different Unicode character to the one you are specifying in your code. Alternatively, perhaps the text is in a different character encoding to your code. Check what character set you are viewing the output in, and see whether it matches the encoding of the PHP script.

**Edit:**

```
function str_ord ($str) {
    $len = strlen($str);
    $my_array = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
        $my_array[] = ord($str[$i]);
    }
    return implode(' ', $my_array);
}
```

Find out what `str_ord()` outputs for `'“'` and for the first few characters of your textarea-string. If it outputs different numbers then you have a character encoding issue.

Comment: ok, so i get 147 for str_ord('“'), and 226 for the first output of str_ord($text). how do i fix the char encoding?

Comment: @Garrett: Check the encoding specified in the http Content-Type header of html page that serves the form. Try changing it to `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: it is: text/html; charset=utf-8
weird...
anyways, i just used strpos($text, chr(226)) === 0, so it works now (thanks to you!)

Comment: @Garrett: I've just added a new answer that I think is a better solution than looking for `chr(226)`. You need to make the `Content-Type` of the form page and the target page consistent. Change them _both_ to `text/html; charset=utf-8`, then paste the code into the textarea and it all should work.

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually using `(string:104)` as part of your `$text` value?

I ask this because I tested with the string:

```
$text = '(string:104) “The diamond cannot be polished without friction, nor the man perfected without trials.”';
```

Which returns a number of the first smart quote.

I then tested:

```
$text = '“The diamond cannot be polished without friction, nor the man perfected without trials.”';
```

Which obviously returns 0, which is also equal to false.
Are you sure you are checking the returned value correctly?

For example:

```
$text = '“The diamond cannot be polished without friction, nor the man perfected without trials.”';

echo strpos($text, '“') !== false ? 'Yay' : 'Nay';
```

Comment: `(string:104)` is the format that PHP's `var_dump` outputs. It gives the type before the actual value. The OP explains that he tests properly using `===`.

Comment: i'm grabbing the text from $_POST, where it is in a textarea

Comment: @Garrett I just tried using a textarea to post the value and now I can see your problem. Unfortunately I don't know why it is doing this and don't have time to find out but perhaps it would be worthwhile trying to convert to smart quotes into html entities, or back to normal quotes?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
strpos($text, """");
```

Comment: classic! _if you came from VB_

Comment: thats invalid php, at least for me

Comment: @Garrett it is indeed invalid. I comment that because the code is valid if you type it in at least VB or VBScript code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$text = '(string:104) "The diamond cannot be polished without friction, nor the man perfected without trials." Chinese Proverb';
echo strpos($text, '"');
?>
```

> 13

I'm not sure what you're issue with this is. it seems to be working fine locally, possibly you have defined the string without said character?

Comment: he is looking for smart quote.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with your PHP. My test below got result:

```
<?php

$text = "   “The diamond cannot be polished without friction, nor the man perfected without trials.” Chinese Proverb";

echo strpos($text, '“');
```

it produce:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The page containing your form is likely being served with different charset than your php script is expecting. They need to be consistent with each other.

Try adding this line to the top of the php page that serves the form *and* the php page that receives the form post:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

As above by Sour Lemon,

```
$str='"This text"';
echo strpos($str, '"');
```

produces 0, which is false so one needs to explicitly compare to false, i.e.

```
if(strpos($str, '"')!==false)
   echo "Found it.";
else
 echo "Dangit, not again! Why wont this thing work?";`
```

produces "Found it."